# Eslint redundant warnings

Tags: eslint

I have a lot of redundant and strange output from eslint and I don't know how it can be disabled. On the screenshot below you can see that there are 5 or 6 repeated problems in every file that not related to actual problems with code.

[image]

For example first line of every file contains this warning.

```
Rule 'no-reserved-keys' was removed and replaced by: quote-props
```

In .eslintrc rule quote-props is disabled.

```
"quote-props": 0
```

But no-reserverd-keys rule enabled instead

```
"no-reserved-keys": 1
```

They defined in additionalRuleMetadata section:

```
"no-reserved-keys": {
    "severity": "w",
    "help": "http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-reserved-keys",
    "priority": "major",
    "category": "Possible Error"
},

"quote-props": {
    "severity": "i",
    "help": "http://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props",
    "category": "Stylistic Issue"
},
```

So the question is. How to get rid from these redundant warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're defining ESLint 1.0 rules but are using ESLint 2.0.

According to the [ESLint docs for `no-reserved-keys`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-reserved-keys):

> **Replacement notice**: This rule was removed in ESLint v1.0 and replaced by the quote-props rule.

You can remove the `no-reserved-keys` rule from your ESLint configuration, but leave the `quote-props` as is and the redundant warnings should go away.

The same is true for:

- `space-return-throw-case`
- `no-wrap-func`
- `global-strict`
- `no-empty-label`

Each was replaced with the rule mentioned in the warnings you're seeing. More info on [migrating to ESLint 2.0](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0#removed-rules).

Comment: Is there any possibility to just turn off such warnings? It seems that I can't just rewrite rules file.

Comment: Why can't you rewrite the rules file? Can you create a personal config file to extend the rules file perhaps?